# Using JPA to call native Postgresql command

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I am using a third party library to perform mass inserts into a database [PgBulkInsert](https://github.com/bytefish/PgBulkInsert) . It takes inserts that would normally take 30 minutes and performs them in 30 seconds. We have noticed that overtime there is disk usage leakage, but we figure out that performing a [table reindex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-reindex.html) appears to corrcect the issue. I am trying to use my JPA Entity Manager to perform a native update. The below code works but contains potential SQL injection vulnerability.

```
@Stateless
public class ReindexService {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-ds")
  private EntityManager em;

  public void reindexTable(String table) {
    String queryStr = "REINDEX TABLE " + table;
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
    query.executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

When I pass in string "alert" to index the alert table it yields the following SQL output

```
/* dynamic native SQL query */ REINDEX TABLE alert
```

When I attempt to use a positional parameter it yields a SQL error

```
String queryStr = "REINDEX TABLE ?";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
query.setParameter(1, table);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This yields the following error output

```
/* dynamic native SQL query */ REINDEX TABLE ?
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
Position: 46
```

I get a similar error when I try to use a name parameter

```
String queryStr = "REINDEX TABLE :table";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
query.setParameter("table", table);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This yields the same error

```
/* dynamic native SQL query */ REINDEX TABLE ?
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
Position: 46
```

Does anyone know how I can call a the native Postgresql reindex table command using my entity manager in a manner without adding a SQL injection vulnerability? I am using Hibernate 5.3.6.Final but would prefer a non-implementation specific solution.

I also tried to access the Connection and perform a JDBC call and it seems to give the error

```
final Session session = //get session from entity manager
session.doWork(conn -> {
  try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(REINDEX TABLE ?)) {
    stmt.setString(1, table);
    stmt.execute();
  }
});
```

Yields the same errors as above

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
Position: 15
```

Comment: You can't pass identifiers (=table name) as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our workaround was to create a Database Function and call it using a native query

The database function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reindex_table(table_in text)
RETURNS void
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('REINDEX (VERBOSE) TABLE %I', table_in);
RETURN;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the Service code for calling the function

```
public void reindexTable(String table) {
  String queryStr = "select reindex_table(?)";
  final Session session = //obtain Hibernate Session from Entitymanager
  session.doWork(conn -> {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(queryStr)) {
      stmt.setString(1, table);
      stmt.execute();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers can't be passed as parameters. If you don't expect the table name to come from user input (it sounds a bit strange), you may try using an enumeration of all the tables which you want to reindex, and pass enumeration values to your service (and just concatenate strings).

If you do expect table names to come from untrusted sources, you can try enclosing identifier with double-quotes and escaping existing double-quotes.

There is also a function [quote_ident](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in PostgreSQL which can be used  to quote identifiers properly. So you can create a stored procedure which takes a regular argument from your JPA code and uses quote_ident and [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) a constructed query 
.

Comment: I tried wrapping the parameter with the quote_ident function call but it gave a SQLError


    /* dynamic native SQL query */ REINDEX TABLE quote_ident(?)
    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
    ERROR: syntax error at or near "("


I am going to try wrapping the call in a stored procedure and call that.

Comment: `REINDEX TABLE quote_ident(?)`

It will not work this way. REINDEX TABLE needs an identifier. You can use quote_ident in combination with REINDEX only if you build and run your query with EXECUTE call in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is something weird ,But Just try, table is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL. So try changing the variable name.

```
String queryStr = "REINDEX TABLE :tableName";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
query.setParameter("tableName", "AUTH_IND");
query.executeUpdate();
```

From the Documentation :

"select" could be used to refer to a column or table named “select”, whereas an unquoted select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html